In CMake, is there a way to get a SHARED/MODULE library target's filename without explicitly setting it?
In CMake, is there a way to get the filename (either basename or absolute filepath) of a MODULE target without explicitly setting it?
The CMake documentation implies that the way to do this is to use the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME property with the get_target_property() function.
But the following attempt to use it doesn't work:
// foo.c
int the_answer() { return 42; }

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(get-lib-name VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)

add_library(foo MODULE foo.c)

get_target_property(LIB_NAME foo LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME)
message("LIB_NAME: ${LIB_NAME}")

$ rm -rf ./build/ && cmake -B build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
LIB_NAME: LIB_NAME-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/scratch/cmake-lib-name/build

But I noticed that if I explicitly set the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME property, I can subsequently get it:
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(get-lib-name VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)

add_library(foo MODULE foo.c)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME "mylibfoo.so"
  )

get_target_property(LIB_NAME foo LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME)
message("LIB_NAME: ${LIB_NAME}")

$ rm -rf ./build/ && cmake -B build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
LIB_NAME: mylibfoo.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/scratch/cmake-lib-name/build

CMake obviously has some intelligent inbuilt defaults: it is not necessary to explicitly set the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME property on a MODULE/SHARED library target: by default CMake will name such targets lib.so (on Linux).
How can I get a MODULE/SHARED library target's output filename whether or not it's been explicitly set?
E.g. given the above (on Linux), I'd like to get a value of "libfoo.so" -- both basename and absolute filepath are okay.

I've tried RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME and OUTPUT_NAME; both behave the same as above, with LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME.
